# Python or Ruby for a new application on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm a (daily) Ruby developer and a (only at home) Python developer.

I well known that Python is installed on (almost all?) Linux machine and so I was wondering if it make sense to write the new application with Ruby, and so having ruby as dependencies or if I should go more for Python ?

Answer (score 1):

Or go for Perl. Perl is really on every single machine, even available on OpenWrt, and it's more similar to Ruby than Python. Hmmm?

PS: I'm ready for the downvotes. Bring them on. :-)